# The opposite of .get() (ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I would just like to ask,

I have an arraylist and I have a String.

When I use .get(Int), I get the String!

Now how would I get that Integer from a String?

Thanks in advance,

CP02A

Comment: `indexOf(Object)`

Comment: how is this the opposite of .get?

Comment: Suggest you read the javadocs for list: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html  Should be obvious.

Comment: Are you asking how to get `index (position) of` that `element` in your list?

Comment: @Amir. With `get`, you input the index and it outputs the object. With `indexOf`, you input the object, and it outputs the index.

Comment: oh, ok, -- in that sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.indexOf(Object o)` method which returns, as the java 8 documentation specifies:

> the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

You can also use `.lastIndexOf(Object o)` which, as you would guess, will return the last occurrence of the specified element.

Please consult the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more details.

Cheers.